# Displaying the data from JSON in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to output the company name and number for each company. Then I will be able to display in my div in a list.
I am not really great at jquery, Ajax and Json so feel a little confused as to what I am doing.

This is the code I have written so far

```
function companywith(elem){

            var companyWithidList = '#companyWith#';

            var ajaxResponse = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/mysite/com/mysite/agcharts.cfc',
                data: {method: 'getChartInfo', returnformat: 'json', company_idlist: companyWithidList},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var json_obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));


                }

            })

        }
```

I get back the data I expected to get back but I want to display this data. I know I need to use a nested loop as I have two arrays.

This is an example of the data that is being displayed in my console but I just dont know how to access it so I can display in my web page.

console display ------>>>>>>
    {COLUMNS: Array(2), DATA: Array(155)}
    COLUMNS
    :
    (2) ["COMPANY_NO", "COMPANY_NAME"]
    DATA
    :
    Array(155)
    [0 … 99]
    0
    :
    (2) [69, "company 1"]
    1
    :
    (2) [41, "company 2"]
    2
    :
    (2) [130, "company 3"]

I added an each loop but this just displays for the first array which is wrong but I am not sure how to add in the second array.

```
    $.each(json_obj, function(i, v) {
    console.log("key is " + i);
    console.log("value is " + v);
    // parse the option value from json into an object
    var obj = JSON.parse(v);

  })
console display ---->>>>>>
key is COLUMNS
value is COMPANY_NO,COMPANY_NAME
```

If you need anymore info please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display data in tables there are many plugin for that. But one of  the best is datatables plugin https://datatables.net/.

Or you can append in this way either if your json is in this format instead array of objects

`[{
  "COMPANY_NAME":"abc",
  "COMPANY_NO":"1224"
  },
  {
  "COMPANY_NAME":"pac",
  "COMPANY_NO":"9224"
  }]`

```
      <table id="output">

      </table> 

         success: function(data){ 
                        $.each(json_obj, function( index, value ) {
                           var row = $("<tr><td>" + value.COMPANY_NAME + "</td><td>" + value.COMPANY_NO + "</td></tr>");
                           $("#output").append(row);
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that your response is like the following:

```
{
  COLUMNS : ["COMPANY_NO", "COMPANY_NAME"],
  DATA : [[69, "company 1"], [41, "company 2"] .....
}
```

Rather than using the whole response, you can use the `data` part of the response, and iterate over that and use it as you see fit
So your success callback  function would be something like

```
 success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                var json_obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
                $.each(json_obj["DATA"], function(i, v) { //you loop over the DATA part only
                  console.log("key is " + i);   //this would be index, say 0
                  console.log("value is " + v); //this would be [69, "company 1"]
                  // use the values
                  console.log("id: "+ v[0]);  // 69
                  console.log("name: "+ v[1]);// "company 1"
                });
            }
```

However please note, the individual entries (like `[69, "company 1"]`) are arrays. They can be handled better if they were json objects (so that you can access by each property name, rather than the position number), in which case your response would contain an array of object rather than the array of arrays it has now.

EDIT: You can also do the iteration without jQuery as follows:

```
response["DATA"].forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);    //Array [ 69, "company 1" ]
  console.log(element[0]+","+element[1]); //69,company 1
});
```